# docker allows me to run containers but where is no output

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run containers with web interface,
and expect to see a web page but where is non

and what is strange is that container with restart on crush does not stop or restart
no indication of crushing

error begin after I tried to run possibly broken container
and now no containers run properly

I've tried to get log output from fresh container to see iv it runs at all
and started simplest hello world one

```
version: '2'
services:
  hello_world:
    image: ubuntu
    command: [/bin/echo, 'Hello World']
```

output was as expected
`docker-compose up --build`

```
Creating temp_hello_world_1 ... done
Attaching to temp_hello_world_1
hello_world_1  | Hello World
temp_hello_world_1 exited with code 0
```

when i started kanboard docker-container

```
version: '2'
services:
  kanboard:
    image: kanboard/kanboard:latest
    ports:
      - "888:80"
      - "8888:443"
    volumes:
      - kanboard_data:/var/www/app/data
      - kanboard_plugins:/var/www/app/plugins
      - kanboard_ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
    networks:
      - kanboard_net
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql://kanboard:kanboard-secret@db/kanboard
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: kanboard
      MYSQL_USER: kanboard
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: kanboard-secret
  db:
    image: mariadb:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: kanboard
      MYSQL_USER: kanboard
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: kanboard-secret
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - kanboard_net
volumes:
  kanboard_data:
  kanboard_plugins:
  kanboard_ssl:
  db:

networks:
  kanboard_net:
    driver: bridge
    external: false
    name: kanboard_net
```

`docker-compose up --build`

only db output any log

```
Attaching to kanboardd_db_1, kanboardd_kanboard_1
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.1.2-MariaDB-1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 9bc25d98209df6810f7a7d5e7dd3ae677a313ab5 as process 1
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffered log writes (block size=512 bytes)
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=47497
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 47497; transaction id 16
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 231020 12:14:05
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Warning] 'default-authentication-plugin' is MySQL 5.6 / 5.7 compatible option. To be implemented in later versions.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1        | 2023-10-20 12:14:05 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
db_1        | Version: '11.1.2-MariaDB-1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:22:33 0 [Note] mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:22:33 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:22:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:22:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:22:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 231020 17:22:34
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:22:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:22:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 47497; transaction id 17
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:22:34 0 [Note] mariadbd: Shutdown complete
db_1        |
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:53+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.1.2-MariaDB-1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision 9bc25d98209df6810f7a7d5e7dd3ae677a313ab5 as process 1
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffered log writes (block size=512 bytes)
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=47497
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 47497; transaction id 16
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 231020 17:24:54
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Warning] 'default-authentication-plugin' is MySQL 5.6 / 5.7 compatible option. To be implemented in later versions.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1        | 2023-10-20 17:24:54 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
db_1        | Version: '11.1.2-MariaDB-1:11.1.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping kanboardd_kanboard_1 ... done
Stopping kanboardd_db_1       ... done
```

web client is offline even if
`docker ps`
does contain them

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                          NAMES
39362c2708c8   kanboard/kanboard:latest   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   43 minutes ago   Up 30 seconds   0.0.0.0:888->80/tcp, :::888->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8888->443/tcp, :::8888->443/tcp   kanboardd_kanboard_1
862118ed7278   nodejs                     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 hours ago      Up 45 minutes   0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp   nodejs
4b6c8318da8a   mariadb:latest             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 hours ago      Up 31 seconds   3306/tcp                                                                       kanboardd_db_1
```

**adding info after last comments**
`localhost:888` has the same effect. docker is on my local server, with local ip 192.168.0.228 on port 888
so its basically the same

resault of curl and ping returns 'This site can’t be reached' for the hosting machine and for machine in the local network

`docker-compose ps` returns

```
        Name                      Command               State                                     Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
kanboardd_db_1         docker-entrypoint.sh --def ...   Up      3306/tcp
kanboardd_kanboard_1   /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh     Up      0.0.0.0:8888->443/tcp,:::8888->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:888->80/tcp,:::888->80/tcp
```

resault after

```
docker-compose down -v --remove-orphans
docker-compose up -d
```

did not change

kanboard is not the only not working container
any containing service of some sort does not respond the same way

for example in `docker ps` u can see nodejs, it's just a web page and no response, all of my containers was up like a week ago and worked properly so they themselves not broken

**more additional info**
so, bad request on curl looks like this

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   248  100   248    0     0   182k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  242k
```

and curl on my services updates once every second like it trying to start
or like it getting response

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:09 --:--:--     0
```

Comment: "*web client is offline even if `docker ps` does contain them*" - What do you mean by "offline"? the container is obviously running. --- What URL are you using to access the web page? --- How is this post related to programming?

Comment: @Turing85 i mean that `http://192.168.0.228:888` returns 'This site can’t be reached' ping or curl dosen't reach from machine from same network or even from the same machine

Comment: ... try `localhost:888`

Comment: What does `docker compose ps` give? Start from fresh by running `docker compose down -v --remove-orphans` and then `docker compose up -d`.

Comment: @Turing85
 i added some additional info which answers your comments

Comment: @msrumon
 i added some additional info which answers your comments

Comment: @NikPlayAnon It's not `888`. The port is `8888`. Check `localhost:8888`.

Comment: @itismoej im checking both, and the fact that ports are open

Comment: The problem is that your issue is NOT reproducible. I tried to run your compose file and could see [the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tK9Lv.png).

Comment: @msrumon i know that problem is not in docker-compose file its in docker itself, i can not understand in what exactly. I've ran in  to problems with docker.socket before, but it is something else. i cant find any way it witch it might have broke

Answer (score 0):

so, i haven't found an answer or cause of this problem, and reinstalled docker
now it works perfectly

[uninstall manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-docker-engine)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).